# Get the value of an annotation with reflection (without knowing the concrete annotation type)

Tags: java, reflection

I have the following class:

```
public final class SomeClass {
    
    @Signature("some info")
    public void someMethod() {

    }

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
    @Inherited
    private @interface Signature {

        String value();
    }    
}
```

This class is not in my source code nor in a dependency, it's compiled from a resource file on-the-fly at runtime. That means, the symbol `Signature.class` (as well as `SomeClass.class`) do not exist in my class loader and will never do at compile time, so I can't do the easy:

```
Signature signature = method.getAnnotation(Signature.class);
signature.value();
```

I would like to retrieve the value that is assigned to the annotation `@Signature` at runtime, but I'm being unable to.
All I know is that the method will only have one annotation (the `@Signature` annotation) and that this annotation will always have one parameter `value`, but that's all I know.

This is my (raw) attempt:

```
Class<?> compiledClass = compiler.compile(classSourceCode); //this properly return the class instance
for (Method method : compiledClass.getDeclaredMethods()) {
    for (Annotation annotation : method.getAnnotations()) {
        Class<? extends Annotation> realType = annotation.annotationType();
        for (Method annotationMethod : realType.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            System.out.println(annotationMethod.invoke(annotation)); //<-- THIS FAILS
        }
    }
}
```

The failure that I get at runtime is:

> java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class SomeClass cannot access a member of interface SomeClass$Signature with modifiers "public abstract"

The method that I get is the method `value()`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like pre-java 11. (Java 11 has [nestmate based access control](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/181)). The class is private - without nest based access controls you can't invoke the method. Use `annotationMethod.setAccessible(true)` before invoking the method.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn oh gorsh that was it, I hadn't even notice the interface was private (the error message is absolutely not clear). If you write this as an answer I'll accept it, thanks a lot